# Como faço para esconder o container enquanto carrega uma imagem?

Tags: jquery

Gostaria de saber como esconder o conteúdo e mostrar somente um gif de *loading* na página. Eu consegui implementar mas as imagens continuam aparecendo, como resolver isto? Meu código esta aqui:

Aqui é a parte em javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Esconde preloader
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#preload').fadeOut(1500);
    });

});
```

E este é o nome da minha div:

```
<div id="preload"><img src="algumacoisa.gif"></div>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar pois este somente não esconde o conteúdo da pagina ate que carregue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse efeito que descreves é chamado [*flash of unstyled content* (FOUC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content), e a única maneira de o evitar é ter o modo default (ou seja por defeito) com regras CSS.

Dá uma classe de CSS que esconda tudo o que não queres que seja visto e mostra somente o que queres removendo essa classe.

Também podes juntar uma div overlay, tipo pano de fundo, mas mais uma vez via CSS.

Exemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Esconde preloader
    $(window).load(function () {.ready()
        $("#preload").animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1000, function () {
            this.remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/e0tttcfr/

Comment: no caso então teria que esconder o container e depois quando as imagens forem carregas mostrar ele?

Comment: isso vai ser muito útil para eu mostrar itens em uma tabela que estou criando, obrigado!

Comment: @LeonardoCosta exato. E dependendo de como tens o HTML talvez seja possivel com css transitions em vez de jQuery

Comment: obrigado deu certo ja